# Weblogic 12c (12.2.1) jax ws and servlet issue

Tags: servlets, weblogic

When deploying a Jax-ws webservice in Weblogic 12c, I am getting the issue

> “weblogic.management.DeploymentException: [HTTP:101401]The url-pattern
>   /PlatforrmTestService in web application example is mapped to multiple
>   Servlets”

class:

```
@WebService(serviceName ="PlatforrmTestService",
    wsdlLocation="WEB-INF/wsdl/pricing_V10/PlatforrmTestService.wsdl",
    ) 
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/PlatforrmTestService"})
public class TestService extends HttpServlet{
...
}
```

Please help to resolve the same.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use @WebServlet annotation if you specify "serviceName" parameter in @WebService.

It seems that WL12.2 is more strict than earlier versions

Rem: I suppose your web.xml don't have servlet and servlet-mapping.

Actually you shouldn't use @WebServlet anymore with @WebService annotation in WL12.2. Here is the simplest WS you can deploy with WL12.2

```
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public class EchoTestWebService{
    public String echoTestWebMethod(String word) {
        return word;
    }
}
```

with an empty web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
</web-app>
```

By default the class name is used for the "serviceName" and all public method are WebMethod.